# Sort episodes into Anime based categories from file/folder names

Tags: c#, .net, regex, sorting, filenames

I need to analyse a number of remote sources and choose the best episode files from each particular Anime title. The deciding factors are mainly video quality and file size.

My current solution is to sort all available files from a source into Anime-Title based category, and later mark all the duplicates once all sources are analysed. *But the varying file names and typos have lead to an unsatisfying number of false-positives*

All of the sources have a large amount of files, most of which are segregated into appropriate Anime title *(but not all)*. I'm trying to categorize all the files to a [list of Anime titles](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/reports.php?id=155&nlist=all) *(I got from Anime News Network)*. For a particular file I'm splitting the file name into word-based keywords and looking for a match with each entry in the title's list. I'm awarding a score to the file for a match and further boosting the score if the folder name also matches the same category.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in allFiles)
{
    string[] subStrings = file.Name.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // score holds a value for each title, highest score indicates closer match
    int[] score = new int[titles.Count];
    bool hasAScore = false;
    // list's length - 1 to avoid extensions from being checked
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < subStrings.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            // @\b defines the match to be specific to whole words
            if (Regex.IsMatch(titles[i], @"\b" + subStrings[j] + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                foreach (string s in file.Directory.Name.Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(titles[i], @"\b" + s + @"\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    {
                        score[i]++;
                    }
                }               
                score[i]++;
                hasAScore = true;
                // Console.WriteLine("Found match with title '{0}' with string '{1}' from file '{2}'", titles[j], subStrings[i], file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    if (hasAScore)
    {
        // Find the highest score in the list and use it's title value as the title of the Category
        string titleName = titles[Array.IndexOf(score, score.Max())];
        bool exists = false;
        // Check through all the categories if it already exists, otherwise add a new one
        // TODO perhaps check this in the class's constructor
        foreach (Category c in categories)
        {
            if (c.Name == titleName)
            {
                c.AddChildren(file, titleName);
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!exists)
        {
            categories.Add(new Category(file, titleName));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Files without a score were not matched with any existing category
        notSorted++;
    }
}
return categories;
}
```

This lead to a lot of false positives because some titles in the database had longer names and smaller verbs boosted the scores. I applied a check for the ratio in the file name and the matched title, but this hasn't helped much with the sorting either.

```
// if the percentage of word matches and total words in the title is > 80% (arbitrary value)
// boost the score
int titleWordCount = titles[i].Split(removables, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
if ((100 * (score[i])/ (2 * titleWordCount)) > 80)
{
    score[i] += 2;
}
```

I've tried to only check for Anime TV titles (and avoid Movie, OVA releases) but the results are still not satisfying.

Most of the files are either downloaded off Torrent or from encoder websites, leading to complex file names including file quality and encoder signature.

**For example:**

```
ShingekinoKyojinOVA-01(480p)[Hatsuyuki-Kaitou][D8E8CC75].mkv -- Category "Shingeki no Kyojin"
(Hi10)_Gosick_-_22_The_Christmas_Carol_Adorns_the_Happiness_by_the_Window_(BD_720p)_(Broken).mkv -- Category "Gosick"
[AnimeKens.com]_[sofcj-raws]_SnK-Oad_1_[SD-480].mkv -- Category "Shingeki no Kyojin"
Commie_Steins Gate 01 Prologue to the Beginning and End.mkv -- Category "Steins Gate"
Commie_Steins_Gate_02_BD_720p_AnimeKens.com.mkv -- Category "Steins Gate"
```

Any ideas on how I should solve this problem? Are there any open source libraries for this sort of problem?

Or should I implement a machine learning module to predict the title from file name? But then I won't have a fixed number of input variables.

Please help, also if this is the right place to ask this question. If not please point me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Try searching web for "lexigraphical search algorithm"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many years ago, I had to come up with some code to match different editions of books in a catalogue database. At first, not too complex.

Then we dug into the actual data. Titles changed (perhaps from 'A fantastic guide to X' to 'A new fantastic guide to X'). Authors came and went from group authored titles. Publishers changed. There were so many different ways of a book changing from one edition to the next that any fully automated solution threw up far too many false positives and false negatives, no matter what we tried (short of a full list of mappings, and if we had that....).

So we put a human in the loop. Gave them a list of candidate matches, with our guess at their likelihood of being right. Sorted so best matches came first, and then on down. At first everyone thought it was a nasty job for someone, but when it got going it proved actually both quick and simple.

This is what I'd do in your situation. The perfect automated solution to this is bordering on a snipe hunt; murderously difficult to get anywhere near reliable, and will depress you at how bad people are at reliably entering titles into the bargain. If at all possible, run the sort of calculations you're doing then stick the candidate matches in front of a human. Faster, cheaper and better in my experience.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if that's feasible :)